# IEnumerable extension methods (System.Linq) unavailable when inheriting from collection and implementing enumerable interfaces

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, linq-extensions

**Problem**
If I have a class with a definition like this:

```
public class TestList : ObservableCollection<TestClass>, IList<ITestInterface>, ICollection<ITestInterface>, IEnumerable<ITestInterface>, IEnumerable
```

I cannot use the `IEnumerable` extension methods (`System.Linq` namespace) on objects of this class.

**Things to Note**

- The type in the `ObservableCollection` is different than the type in the collection interfaces, but `TestClass` does implement `ITestInterface`
- It is still possible to `foreach` over the items in a `TestList` object. Doing so gives the items the type of `TestClass`
- I do have a `using` statement for `System.Linq` at the top of the file

It clearly has something to do with the fact that the type in the `ObservableCollection` is different than the other types in the class definition, but why? The collection can still be enumerated in a `foreach` statement, and that is basically what those extension methods do anyways (with additional logic of course).

**Question**
Why does creating a class that inherits from a collection of one type and implements collection interfaces of another type cause the extension methods in `System.Linq` to be unavailable to use on objects of the class?

**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace TestApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var t = new TestList();

            t.First(); //Extension method unavailable, compiler error

            foreach (var item in t)
            {
                //item is of type TestClass
            }
        }

    }

    public interface ITestInterface { }


    public class TestClass : ITestInterface { }


    public class TestList : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<TestClass>, IList<ITestInterface>, ICollection<ITestInterface>, IEnumerable<ITestInterface>, IEnumerable
    {
        //Method implementations are unnecessary for the example
        ITestInterface IList<ITestInterface>.this[int index] { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public bool IsReadOnly => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void Add(ITestInterface item) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool Contains(ITestInterface item) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void CopyTo(ITestInterface[] array, int arrayIndex) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public int IndexOf(ITestInterface item) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public void Insert(int index, ITestInterface item) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        public bool Remove(ITestInterface item) => throw new NotImplementedException();

        IEnumerator<ITestInterface> IEnumerable<ITestInterface>.GetEnumerator() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Background**
For those that are curious, I came across this while working with the Telerik RadGridView control (WPF). I was trying to use the `.First()` extension method on the `Columns` property of the grid, but the type of the `Columns` property has a class definition that is similar to what I provided above.

Comment: Well, that's quite confusing. I'd probably just rely on the non-generic `IEnumerable` portion of your inheritance and `.Cast<ITestInterface>()` to bring it back to a "LINQable" state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off: **please do not do this**. You have implemented both `IEnumerable<TestClass>` and `IEnumerable<ITestInterface>` on the same type and this can cause some *really* nasty problems.

For example: `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, so if you convert your type to `IEnumerable<Object>`, what happens? Does the sequence of objects contain only `TestClass` objects or can it contain any object that implements `ITestInterface`?  Hard to say! (For an extended discussion of this point, see the comments on my 2007 article on this subject: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/11/09/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-ten-dealing-with-ambiguity/)

The particularly nasty situation you're in is, as the other answer notes, the type inference step of overload resolution is unable to deduce what the type argument of `First<T>` should be because there are two incompatible options. A smaller repro would be:

```
public class C : IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<object>
{
    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator() => null;
    IEnumerator<object> IEnumerable<object>.GetEnumerator() => null;
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => null;
}
```

And now `new C().First()` gives you the same error.

The error message is horrid, and I apologize for that. The common case is that there is no such applicable extension method and the error message is optimized for that case. It would have been better to detect that the *reason* that there was no applicable extension method was due to type inference failure. In other error reporting scenarios I did that, but not this one.

Consider reporting an issue on GitHub and perhaps this one can get fixed.

Comment: thanks for the info! Is there anything at all to be gained from doing this? Even if the benefits don't outweigh the costs? Like I mentioned at the bottom of my post, I stumbled across this in a third party library, so just curious if there is a reason it was built like this.

Comment: @Alex: You'd have to ask the library authors. A possible factor is that perhaps the type was designed before we added covariance to C# 4, and they had a scenario for supporting two different kinds of sequences in the same object.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the compiler has no enough type information to unambiguously infer the type parameter of the generic `First<T>()` method. The possible type parameters in your case are `TestClass` and `ITestInterface`.

You can help the compiler by specifying the type argument explicitly. The following will compile:

```
var item1 = t.First<TestClass>();
var item2 = t.First<ITestInterface>();
```

And yes, the compiler could have produced a better error message.

Comment: Wow, that was pretty dumb of me to not even try to specify the type. I guess I was just thrown off by the method not appearing in Intellisense. Thanks!